# datepicker kartik's widget doesn't show the calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, widget, yii2

I have a project using YII2 framework and kartik widgets. I had a problem with kartik's datepicker, when I use a datepicker class into my project, the datepicker doesn't shows the calendar.

how to resolve this problem?

this is my view's code

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\TbInputStok */
/* @var $form kartik\widgets\ActiveForm */

$this->title = 'Input Barang Masuk';
?>

<div class="tb-input-stok-inputStok">
<h1><?= $this->title ?></h1>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'nama')->textInput(['disabled'=>'disabled', 'value' => $modelKaryawan->nama]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'nama_barang')->textInput(['disabled' => 'disabled', 'value' => $modelBarang->nama_barang]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'jumlah')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'tanggal')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter event time ...'],
'pluginOptions' => [
'autoclose' => true
]
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'foto_surat_jalan')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'id_barang')->hiddenInput(['value' => $modelBarang->id_barang])->label(false) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'id_karyawan')->hiddenInput(['value' => $modelKaryawan->id_karyawan])->label(false) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Tambah' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: any browser console errors ?

Comment: yes, the eror is
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).parent(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Most probably this might be because your site is loading two jquery.js files. Second one being loaded after it loads the js file related to the datepicker widget. Check on that.

Comment: thanks man, you're right